# Exception Handling with Agatha Framework (BusinessExceptionType)

Tags: c#, exception, agatha-rrsl

I am using the [Agatha](http://davybrion.github.io/Agatha/) framework with a custom exception. I have an exception, `MyException`, which I am specifying as the `BusinessExceptionType` when I configure my request:

```
new ServiceLayerConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), typeof(SomeRequestResponse.MakeARequest).Assembly, typeof(Container)) { BusinessExceptionType = typeof(MyException) }.Initialize();
```

This is how I am throwing that exception:

```
throw new MyException(message);
```

When the exception is thrown, however, `MyException` is not recognized as a `BusinessExceptionType`. How do I get it to be recognized as a `BusinessExceptionType`? The below condition is not true.

```
if (response.ExceptionType == ExceptionType.Business)
```

Here is the exception class:

```
public class MyException : Exception
{
    public MyException()
    {

    }

    public MyException(string message) : base(message)
    {

    }

    public MyException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner)
    {

    }

    protected MyException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context)
    {

    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
It appears the `BusinessExceptionType` is set in the `serviceLayerConfiguration` correctly until I make my first request when the `BusinessExceptionType` becomes `null`. Somewhere in-between configuring the request and making my first request it becomes `null`. Either that, or it is grabbing a different `serviceLayerConfiguration` in the `RequestProcessor.cs`. Any help with this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered you must set the exception type in the response before throwing it.

```
return new SomeRequestResponse.MakeAResponse() { Exception = new Exception(ex), ExceptionType = ExceptionType.Business };
```

Then in your consumer this statement will be true:

```
if (response.ExceptionType == ExceptionType.Business)
```

You can also do this if you want to make your own exception:

```
return new MakeARequestResponse.MakeAResponse()
{
    Exception = new ExceptionInfo(new Exception("Whatever you want to say.")),
    ExceptionType = ExceptionType.Business
};
```